# How to include 'data-urlencode' using php curl library

Tags: php, curl, twilio

I am trying to connect twilio api using Curl php. The following is the code from Twilio api

I used an online tool php to curl but it didn't converted the code with data encode url.

The question which was marked as duplicate has no information about --data-urlencode. I have tried the solution mentioned there but still it is not working the way it is suppose to.

```
curl -X POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNTID/Messages.json \
--data-urlencode "From=+122344444" \
--data-urlencode "Body=Body" \
--data-urlencode "To=+13101111111" \
-u ACCOUNTID:PASSWORD
```

PHP Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ACCOUNTID' . ':' . 'PASSWORD');
```

The expected result is to get message but I am getting

```
{"code": 21603, "message": "A 'From' phone number is required.", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/21603", "status": 400}
```

The reason I am getting this is I am not sure how to pass from, body and to in curl php.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: thank you but I have seen them earlier and tried them somehow from to parameters aren't working @Emma

Comment: i do not see you pass any data in your php code.

Comment: I limited my code due to code policy, all the variables are having data

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you're missing is

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));`

where `$payload` is

```
$payload = [
    'From' => '+122344444',
    'To' => '+13101111111',
    'Body'   => 'This is the body...'
];
```

---

PHP Code:

```
$payload = [
    'From' => '+122344444',
    'To' => '+13101111111',
    'Body'   => 'This is the body...'
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'ACCOUNTID' . ':' . 'PASSWORD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload));
```