# How to add --data-urlencode to PHP cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I have collection on postman and it is working fine. But now, I am trying to convert this PHP cURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://test.url.com' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic 1234567890' \
--data-urlencode 'abc_id=123456' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=req-auth/all'
```

Here is my code:

```
$headers = [
                "Authorization: Basic 1234567890",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencode"
            ];
$data = [ 
            "abc_id" => '123456',
            "grant_type" => 'client_credentials',
            "scope" => 'req-auth/all',
        ];            
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data) 
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$errno = curl_errno($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);
```

I tried this code but it is not working on my end [How to include 'data-urlencode' using php curl library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504755/how-to-include-data-urlencode-using-php-curl-library)

Comment: Try adding a `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true`

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Just do `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data`. No need to build query or URL encode; PHP handles that for you.

Comment: What *exactly* does "not working on my end" mean? Do you get an error somewhere? Click the [edit] link and try to be specific.

Comment: {"message": "Invalid abc_id", "status": 401} I tried adding CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true but still this errors show

Comment: I tried removig the http_build_query but still that error shows @IMSoP

Comment: Is it possible your code is fine and `123456` is actually an invalid abc_id?